# Xquery to get all nodes that has a particular attribue

Tags: c#, xml, xmldom

I have a XML file that has lot of elements with a particular attribute say href. Is there any x query to get all the nodes that has href = "ABC.jpg" ? If not what is the best way to do it ?

Comment: <concept>
  <title>Whatis a concept?</title>
  <conbody>   
    <p id = "11" href = "ABC.xml" </p>
    <p id = "11" href = "XYZ.xml" </p>
    <p id = "12" href = "ABC.xml" </p>
  </conbody>
</concept>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//*[@href = 'ABC.jpg']
```